# LiveCharts2 binding continuously changing data to graph

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I'm new in WPF and C# so go easy on me :)
My goal is to plot data to graph using LiveCharts2 with WPF help and add data live.

I followed the example of LiveCharts2  added the class ViewModel with and the XAML and everything worked fine:

```
    public partial class ViewModel
    {
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } =
        {
        new LineSeries<double>
        {
            Values = new double[] { 1, 2 },
            Fill = null
        }
        };
```

This is static data .. how do I bind it to a variable that changes at any given time? or how should I change the code for that purpose?

I tried to write only XAML code (view code) and took the example from LiveCharts2 to add data to the "Values" but couldn't make it.

I want something like this and just fire and forget & wish that the data plot will update automatically.

```
        new LineSeries<double>
        {
            Values = new double[] { myChangedata },
            Fill = null
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an ObservableCollection instead of an array so the chart can receive updates.

```cs
public partial class ViewModel
{
   private ObservableCollection<double> myChangedData = new();

   public ViewModel()
   {
      Series.Add(new LineSeries<double>
      {
         Values = myChangedData,
         Fill = null,
      });
   }

   public object Sync { get; } = new();

   public List<ISeries> Series { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Then to add data

```cs
lock (Sync)
{
   // Any changes including adding, clearing, etc must be synced.
   myChangedData.Add(1D);
   myChangedData.Add(2D);
}
```

When doing live data be sure you set the SyncContext property on the chart and always lock it before any changes.

```xml
<lc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}" SyncContext="{Binding Sync}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. To make it clear - the code line:
((ObservableCollection<double>)Series[0].Values).Add(1D);
((ObservableCollection<double>)Series[0].Values).Add(2D);
where do I put the command? 
I tried to put it in my MainWindow.xaml.cs  is that the correct way ?

Comment: Typically that would go in your view model, where ever you are collecting data.  I updated my answer to use a private field.  Hopefully that will be more clear.